# Crash when loading older projects

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2017

I have a bigger project that I would like to transfer to Visual Studio 2017. Project was created in VS15 and everytime I try to load it in VS17, about 5 seconds after the project gets loaded, the program crashes - saying usual "Program has stopped working". Creating new project in VS17 does work normally though, without any crashes.

I tried to delete .vs folder, nothing has changed. I tried to change versions in solution file in my project, nothing has changed.

What happens that it crashes few seconds after the project load?

**EDIT: I found it only happens to that one project. So I tried to get further.**

```
Unexpected system error mode before loading package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.Packages.OnlineLicensing.OnlineLicensingManagerPackage]
```

Comment: I would do a repair on VS 2017 and make sure you sign in to visual studio with your Microsoft account.  It does sound like it is trying to install a missing component needed to open the project created in vs 2015 and is getting a licensing error.

Comment: Did it now, problem didn't fix